# Error in passing a map by reference to a function

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers, pass-by-reference

I want to pass a map by reference to a function.
Here is the code:

```
void test(map<int, double *> &a);

int main(){
    map<int, double *> a;
    test(a);
    cout << a[1][1] << endl;
    return 0;
}

void test(map<int, double*> &a)
{
    double red[] = {1.1, 2, 3};
    a[1] = red;
}
```

The problem is that, a[1][1] is supposed to be 2. However, when I execute the program, it gives a big number like 1.73e120 !!!

Comment: weird enough. Your code outputs 2 here: http://ideone.com/lyQAzd

Comment: @tacp it is undefined behaviour. It could output anything.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks. It may be nice to know all undefined behaviors in C++.

Comment: @tacp well, accessing an array out of bounds is one case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double red[] = {1.1, 2, 3};
```

has an automatic storage duration. Which means when the function returns it is no longer valid.

you should do something like this

```
void test(map<int, double*> &a)
{
    double *red = new double[3];
    // fill up red.
    a[1] = red;
}
```

Comment: It's got automatic storage duration, rather than static.

Comment: Dynamic allocation probably isn't the best solution, since now you've made the user responsible for remembering to correctly delete it. Storing an RAII type like `std::array` or `std::vector` would be better.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes he can probably use a vector. Or if all seconds of the map have size N then an N size array. However this is just a solution to his current problem.

Comment: @MikeSeymour and in this case I don't see a problem with using a raw allocation because every pointer goes in to the map immediately. There is no risk of leak as long as he iterates the map at the end and deletes. Which I would do instead of using vector here.

Comment: shouldnt this trigger a copy operation by the map at some point?

Comment: If you have a `map<int, double*>`, how do you know if you should call `delete` or `delete[]`? And how do you know that the elements have not been deleted elsewhere?

Comment: @juanchopanza if I am writing the code I should probably know those things. (And there is no problem if they have been deleted before). I don't know how that can be a reason. That's like saying what if you write `-` instead of `+`.

Comment: How can you know those things? What happens if the map gets copied? A double delete is certainly something that matters.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK. If the map gets copied then he copies everything one by one. The guy asked a simple question. I gave him a simple answer. If you start making assumptions like that from a 10 line sample code then I think I can not argue with you. What I said was that given the fact that the pointers are collected in a proper container the risk for leak is very low. So here you can opt for performance and skip vector. The thing is nothing is really 100% safe anyway you can make mistakes anywhere not just with pointers. It is all about the compromise between performance and convenience.

Answer (score 4):

Your map maps ints to pointers to double. When you add an element inside a function, as you do here,

```
a[1] = red; // points to first element of local red[] array
```

the map is copying a pointer to a local variable. The address it points to makes no sense outside of the `test` function. A pointer is not an array, and an array is not a pointer.

You could fix the problem by using a map of vectors instead:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<double>>
```

then

```
void test(std::map<int, std::vector<double>> &a)
{
  a[1] = std::vector<double>{1.1, 2., 3.};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
double red[] = {1.1, 2, 3};
a[1] = red;
```

Danger! Danger! `red` is a local variable which is destroyed after `test()` returns. Don't store pointers to local variables that will be used after a function has returned.

You could fix this by making it static, since static variables live forever.

```
static double red[] = {1.1, 2, 3};
a[1] = red;
```

Or you could allocate memory dynamically:

```
double *red = new double[]{1.1, 2, 3};
a[1] = red;
```

Answer (score 4):

The array created by the definition of `red` is local to the `test` function. It will be destroyed when the function ends. You are only placing a pointer to its first element in the `map`, but that pointer no longer points at a valid array once the function returns. The array is gone and the pointer has been left dangling.

You *could* dynamically allocate the array, but this is a massive pain and is likely to result in memory leaks and other bugs.

Instead, I recommend using a standard container type, such as `std::vector`:

```
void test(map<int, std::vector<double>> &a)
{
    a[1] = std::vector<double>{1.1, 2.0, 3.0};
}
```